# Calculating the minimum and maximum of a function using Lagrange multiplier.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

To find the minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)=x^2y+2xy+12y^2$ in the domain $g(x,y)=x^2+2x+16y^2\leq8$, I'll use Lagragian multiplier's method.

$f(x,y)=x^2y+2xy+12y^2$

$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$

$(2xy+2y)\hat i +(x^2+2x+24y)\hat j = \lambda\left( (2x+2)\hat i + 32y\hat j\right)$

$(x+1)y = \lambda(x+1)$

$(y-\lambda) (x+1) = 0\tag 1$

$x^2+2x+24y = 32\lambda y\tag 2$

From (1), it is either $x = -1$ or $\lambda = y$

If $x = -1$

I plug the value of $x$ in $g(x,y)$ to find $y =\pm  \frac{3}{4}$

Wolfram Alpha says $(-1,-3/4)$ is a maximum, so that's OK, my problem comes when $\lambda = y$. If $\lambda = y$, $$x^2+2x+24y-32y^2=0$$ $$\longrightarrow{y=\frac{1}{8}(\sqrt{2x^2+4x+9}+\frac{3}{8}}$$ $$\longrightarrow{y=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{8}(\sqrt{2x^2+4x+9}}$$

But that does not help me in any way (I think). What can I do to find the minimum?

[image: Minimums and maximums by Wolfram Alpha]

Answer (score 1):

You can think that the extremes are either within the region or on the boundary. On the boundary you are solving the problem:

$$
\min/\max:~~ f(x,y)\\
\text{st}:~~~ g(x,y) - 8 =0
$$

As you point out this requires to solve the equations

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla f(x,y) &=& \lambda\nabla[g(x,y) - 8] \\
g(x,y) - 8 &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

which is equivalent to

\begin{eqnarray}
(1+x)(y-\lambda) &=& 0 \tag{1}\\
x^2 + 2x + 24y &=& 32 \lambda y \tag{2}\\
x^2 + 2x + 16 y^2 &=& 8 \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

in the case $y\lambda$, eqns (2) and (3) become

\begin{eqnarray}
x^2 + 2x + 24y &=& 32y^2 \\
x^2 + 2x + 16y^2 &=& 8
\end{eqnarray}

if you add them up you get

$$
24y - 16y^2 = 32y^2 - 8 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ y = \frac{1}{12} (3 \pm \sqrt{33})
$$

From here you can calculate $x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With $x^2+2x+24y-32y^2=0$ and condition $g=0$ you have
$$-48y^2+24y+8=0$$
shows points $y\sim0.7$ and $y\sim-0.2$ and you can continue fro here!